# Power Bi multiplying columns in different tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having problems with these tables. I need to calculate the `(af_escalaItem[valor]*af_servprod_criterios[peso])` for each `af_aval_id`, but I just can't seem to do this.

Please see the images below for a better understanding.

Thank you in advance.

[image: a]

[image: b]

[image: c]

[image: d]

[image: e]

[image: f]

[image: g]

[image: h]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relationship between the tables is set up correctly, you can use the `RELATED()` function to calculate the column:

```
Multiple = RELATED(af_escalaItem[valor]) * RELATED(af_servprod_criterios[peso])
```

---

Edit:

As the relationship between the tables contain composite keys, the following function needs to be used to lookup the value of `peso` instead:

```
Multiple = 
RELATED(af_escalaItem[valor]) * 
CALCULATE(
    VALUES(af_servprod_criterios[peso]),
    FILTER(
        af_servprod_criterios,
        af_avaliacaoItens[af_criterio_id] = af_servprod_criterios[af_criterio_id] &&
        RELATED(af_fornecedorAvalia[af_servprod_id]) = af_servprod_criterios[af_servprod_id]
    )
)
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Can you please check image 8? It has the relationships created. I can't use related to call table af_servprod_criterios. I think there might be a problem with the relationships but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @user2292821 I've checked the screenshot but it's quite challenging to figure out the problem with the relationships with just the screenshots provided. Could you provide the .pbix file or a subset of the data for investigation?

Comment: yes you can find the pbix file here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7z1oVSpYVn5Nl9yOVpoeHNqSjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user2292821 For the `af_servprod_criterios` table, there are different values of `peso` for the same `af_criterio_id`. The column `af_servprod_id` should be key as well, right? Therefore, for the `af_avaliacaoItens` table, there should be a `af_servprod_id` for each record as well?

Comment: @user2292821 I've edited the solution. Please check if it solves your problem.